# php DOTNET class not initializing

Tags: c#, php

I am trying to call C# dll from php script:

```
<?
$stack = new DOTNET("mscorlib", "System.Collections.Stack");
$stack->Push(".Net");
$stack->Push("Hello ");
echo $stack->Pop() . $stack->Pop();
?>
```

I keep on getting DOTNET class not found on running this script

My PHP.INI file is as follows for the following attributes:

```
[COM]
; path to a file containing GUIDs, IIDs or filenames of files with TypeLibs
; http://php.net/com.typelib-file
;com.typelib_file =

; allow Distributed-COM calls
; http://php.net/com.allow-dcom
com.allow_dcom = true

[COM_DOT_NET]
extension=php_com_dotnet.dll

; autoregister constants of a components typlib on com_load()
; http://php.net/com.autoregister-typelib
;com.autoregister_typelib = true

; register constants casesensitive
; http://php.net/com.autoregister-casesensitive
;com.autoregister_casesensitive = false
```

I am using Php5.4 version and I have the php_com_dotnet.dll in the following folder:

```
v5.4\ext
```

Can someone help me out as to what I am missing or information about how I can fix this?

Comment: Sidenote: Short open tags, are they on?

Comment: this is the setting in my php.ini file :short_open_tag = Off   .Should i change it to short_open_tag = On

Comment: Put them on or change `<?` to `<?php` most likely the reason. Should fix the problem.

Comment: i tried setting them to On but it still gives the same issue

Comment: This might sound silly, but do you have the .NET runtime installed on the server?

Comment: i got the issue ,i was trying to run my php script using asp.net local server since i was using vsphp for visual studio .Thanks for the helps guys.It worked fine when when i ran the php from locaLhost IIS